# Read arguments from set /p command as seperate variables in Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

Recently I've been experimenting with some automation scripts, and for some purpoes a text input to input information that will help the program is useful. However, rather then doing it line by line, each word a sep input, I'd rather be fancier at read them as variables using batches parameter variables, and then use them to run a correspending batch program.

```
set /p main=".\ "
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
set arg3=%3
set arg4=%4
%~d0\software\%1.bat %arg2% %arg3% %arg4% %arg5%
```

It worked, when I made it last night. Now it won't and I'm trying to figure out what the error is. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option for you that was discovered on the [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429#p41035). It uses a string substitution syntax that keeps creating a `SET` statement for every delimiter you have.  This allows the code to be a bit more dynamic as it will create an array of variables and isn't dependent on how many arguments the user may or may not input.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p main=".\ "

set i=1
set "arg!i!=%main: =" & set /A i+=1 & set "arg!i!=%"
set arg
pause
```

And here is the script running.

```
.\ arg1 &arg2 |arg3| <arg4>
arg1=arg1
arg2=&arg2
arg3=|arg3|
arg4=<arg4>
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And again to show you it is not limited to the amount of arguments.

```
.\ Jack and Jill ran up the hill
arg1=Jack
arg2=and
arg3=Jill
arg4=ran
arg5=up
arg6=the
arg7=hill
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I should note that this code will have issues with exclamation points as input. Validating input is always difficult in batch.  That is why we have hackers today.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
set /p main=".\ "
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims= " %%a in ('echo %main%') do set arg1=%%a & set arg2=%%b & set arg3=%%c & set arg4=%%d
Rem do anything with these
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Accept the answer by clicking the grey tick mark.

Comment: @user3671588 That may work for you depending on data string entered on being prompted, but it is far away from being perfect. For example run the batch file with this code from within a command prompt window, enter on prompt `arg1 &arg2 |arg3| <arg4>` and see what happens. Better would be as second line `for /F "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%I in ("%main%") do set "arg1=%%I" & set "arg2=%%J" & set "arg3=%%K" & set "arg4=%%L"`, but it is still not fail safe, for example on entering a string with one or more double quotes. There would be required `if defined main set "main=%main:"=%"` above __FOR__.